# Mongodb updateMany property to exact value of other property

Tags: mongodb

I have documents representing Users with onboarding data stored as a nested object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7eb0132e6f793bcc7f4bf7"),
    "userName" : "sample_user_name",
    "onBoarding" : {
        "completed" : ISODate("2019-03-05T17:46:28.803Z"),
        "stepId" : 8,
        "started" : null
    }
}
```

But due to a bug we are missing a date when onboarding was started, I would like to "retrieve" this information by running an update operation where "started" will be set to the same date as "completed". I have a query like:

```
db.getCollection('user').updateMany(
{ 
  $and: [
      {"onBoarding.started": {$exists: false}},
      {"onBoarding.completed": {$exists: true}}
]}, 
{
  $set: { "onBoarding.started": "$onBoarding.completed" }
})
```

This however, sets "started" to "$onBoarding" literally (as a string).

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7eb0132e6f793bcc7f4bf7"),
    "userName" : "sample_user_name",
    "onBoarding" : {
        "completed" : ISODate("2019-03-05T17:46:28.803Z"),
        "stepId" : 8,
        "started" : "$onBoarding"
    }
}
```

How should I write it for mongo to take a value from "onBoarding.completed" and copy this value to "onBoarding.started"??
Expected result document should look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c7eb0132e6f793bcc7f4bf7"),
    "userName" : "sample_user_name",
    "onBoarding" : {
        "completed" : ISODate("2019-03-05T17:46:28.803Z"),
        "stepId" : 8,
        "started" : ISODate("2019-03-05T17:46:28.803Z")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Depends on which version of MongoDB are you using.

Comment: It doesn't, it uses a $concat function which I don't want to use here, how do you even $concat two dates? I want to set "started" to exactly same value as "completed".

Comment: $concat there is just an example to produce a new value from 2 fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: No @AlexBlex it doesn't answer my question. I'm doing updateMany in the same way but without using a $concat function it doesn't work, instead of a date from "onBoarding.completed" it puts "$onBoarding" literally as a string.

Comment: Please read and comprehend the answer - why it is working there and why there are different syntax for different versions. Follow the links to the docs and read details. Concat there is not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html) operator checks for existence of a field. If a field has a value of `null`, the query still returns true (because the field still exists, only its value is null).

The following queries behave differently with this input document: `{ _id: 1, fld1: 123, fld2: null }`

- `db.test.find( { fld2: { exists: false } } )` returns `false`.
- `db.test.find( { fld2: null } } )` returns `true`.

Coming back to the data in question - the following query / script will update all the documents with following condition: ( "onBoarding.started" is `null` *or* the field doesn't exist ) ***and*** ( "onBoarding.completed" field exists *and* is not `null` ).

```
db.test.find( { $and: [ { $or: [ { "onBoarding.started": null },  { "onBoarding.started": { $exists: false } } ] },  { $and: [ { "onBoarding.completed": { $exists: true } }, { "onBoarding.completed": { $ne: null } } ] } ] } ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "onBoarding.started" : doc.onBoarding.completed } } ) )
```

---

Using **MongoDB version 4.2**, the same update can be run as follows. Note the *update* uses an Aggregation stage (see documetation on [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)).

```
db.test.updateMany(
  { $and: [ { $or: [ { "onBoarding.started": null },  { "onBoarding.started": { $exists: false } } ] },  { $and: [ { "onBoarding.completed": { $exists: true } }, { "onBoarding.completed": { $ne: null } } ] } ] },
  [
    { $addFields: 
        { "onBoarding.started" : "$onBoarding.completed" } 
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an aggregation pipeline to be able to use the value of another field :

```
db.user.updateMany(
   { <your query selector > },
   [
      { $set: { onBoarding.started: "$onBoarding.completed" } },
   ]
)
```

Be aware that here, $set refers to the aggregation pipeline stage and not the update operator $set : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-aggregation-pipeline

Comment: How is that different from the operation I was running?

Comment: The square brackets around the $set makes it an aggregation pipeline and not a "simple" $set operator. So it allows you to use the value of another field.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MongoDB version.

```
@Query("{<your query selector>}")
@Update(pipeline = {
    "{ $set : {onBoarding.started: "$onBoarding.completed" } }"
})
void update();
```